# Congestion Window Equation

Tags: congestion

I'm reading through [High Performance Browser Networking](https://hpbn.co/building-blocks-of-tcp/#slow-start) and would like to understand how this equation for congestion window sizing works. I'm not sure if this would be more appropriate on a math forum.

Where does each element in `Time = RTT x [log2(1 + N/initial)]` come from? The round trip time multiplied at the beginning makes sense, because each increment opportunity for adjust the cwnd size will take a round trip. Why the log2, and why the 1 and why the n/initial?

[image: HPBN book equation for time to reach cwnd size of N]